# Rkhunter update skips checking some files

Tags: kali-linux, software-updates, rkhunter

Upon entering the command Rkhunter --update in my Kali Linux distribution. 
The result is as follows

```
[ Rootkit Hunter version 1.4.6 ]

Checking Rkhunter data files...

Checking file mirrors.dat                                  [ No update ]

Checking file programs_bad.dat                             [ No update ]

Checking file backdoorports.dat                            [ No update ]

Checking file suspscan.dat                                 [ No update ]

Checking file i18n/cn                                      [ Skipped ]

Checking file i18n/de                                      [ Skipped ]

Checking file i18n/en                                      [ No update ]

Checking file i18n/tr                                      [ Skipped ]

Checking file i18n/tr.utf8                                 [ Skipped ]

Checking file i18n/zh                                      [ Skipped ]

Checking file i18n/zh.utf8                                 [ Skipped ]

Checking file i18n/ja                                      [ Skipped ]
```

Doing the update it always skips checking some files.
Is this behaviour normal for Rkhunter or some configuration problem has occurred?

My distro is Kali Linux 4.15.0-kali3-amd64

Comment: What are the relevant contents of /var/log/rkhunter.log?

Answer (score 1):

The `i18n/*` files are just for localization purposes, so they are not essential for core program functionality. The output you've posted suggests you already have the English strings.

Side note #1: You shouldn't be running `rkhunter --update` as it is a security risk: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=765895 Install `rkhunter` via `apt` and let your package manager take care of keeping the utility updated.

Side note #2: `rkhunter` can generate a lot of false positives, so be prepared for that.

Comment: Thank you very much and yes due to the false positives I switched to Lynis